# Open New Tab & Focus from Lightning Component in Console

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-components

I currently have a LWC that is embedded within an Aura component. When a user clicks a button on the LWC it will convert a lead and return the new account id. The the Aura component is supposed to then close the lead tab (current tab) and open (then focus) on the new account tab. I have been able to make it so the lead tab closes and the account tab opens **but** it does not focus on the newly opened tab.

Here is the code for the Aura component:

```js
    openTab: function(component, event, helper) {
        
        console.log('Opening Tab 2');
        component.set('v.recordId', event.getParam('value'));
        console.log('Record Id:' + component.get('v.recordId'));
        var recId = component.get('v.recordId');
        console.log(recId);

        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.openTab({
            recordId: recId,
            focus: true
        }).then(function(response) {
            workspaceAPI.getTabInfo({
                  tabId: response
            }).then(function(tabInfo) {
            console.log("The url for this tab is: " + tabInfo.url);
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log('oh no: ' + error);
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
               console.log(error);
        });
        console.log('Tab Opened');
    }
})
```

When Logging, I see the record ids in console but do not see anything after the `console.log(recId)`.

Any assistance that can be provided would be appreciated.

Thanks,